# What type of photo effects is this?

Tags: photoshop

[image]

What app or photo effect is it to get the sparkling or twinkle effect that's circled?

Answer (score 4):

It's generally called a *starburst*. There are filters that attach to your lens that create this effect, software "filters" that add the effect automatically to highlights, and software image effects that let you place a starburst wherever you want. These were pretty clearly applied by hand -- there's no optical reason that the "1" would have a starburst around it.

Comment: It's worth noting that when it's not applied in software, it can be achieved by a [diffraction grating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction_grating).